# In how many ways can m white and n black balls be arranged in a circle so that there shall be 2r contacts between white and black balls?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**In how many ways can $m$ white and $n$ black balls be arranged in a circle so that there shall be 2$r$ contacts between white and black balls? Suppose the balls are identical, but the positions on the circle are distinguishable.**

If I am not mistaken, the total number of arrangements is

$$N=\frac{\left(n+m\right)!}{n!\cdot m!}.$$

Now, my question is how to split $N$ in $N_r$, where $N_r$ would be the number of arrangements with $2r$ contacts of unequal color.

I have calculated a few examples:

- $m=0$ and $n=6$: $N=1$, with $N_0=1$
- $m=2$ and $n=5$: $N=21$, with $N_1=7,N_2=14$
- $m=4$ and $n=4$: $N=70$, with $N_1=8,N_2=36,N_3=24,N_4=2$
- $m=6$ and $n=3$: $N=84$, with $N_1=9,N_2=45,N_3=30$
- $m=8$ and $n=2$: $N=45$, with $N_1=10,N_2=35$
- $m=10$ and $n=1$: $N=11$, with $N_1=11$
- $m=12$ and $n=0$: $N=1$, with $N_0=1$

Finding an analytical expression for $N_r$ would already be of great help. However, in reality, I am even more interested in the following question:

**How does this result change if we suppose that black balls occur only in pairs?**

For this case, I think I also already found an expression for the total number of arrangements (assuming that there is at least one ball of either color; a general solution would be preferred, but it's not a priority):

$$N=\binom{n/2+m-1}{m-1}+2\binom{n/2+m-1}{n/2-1}$$

I can also give some numerical results for $N_r$ in this case, however, I am lacking the analytical expression:

- $m=0$ and $n=12$: $N=1$, with $N_0=1$ (formula above does not work)
- $m=2$ and $n=10$: $N=36$, with $N_1=12,N_2=24$
- $m=4$ and $n=8$: $N=105$, with $N_1=12,N_2=54,N_3=36,N_4=3$
- $m=6$ and $n=6$: $N=112$, with $N_1=12,N_2=60,N_3=40$
- $m=8$ and $n=4$: $N=54$, with $N_1=12,N_2=42$
- $m=10$ and $n=2$: $N=12$, with $N_1=12$
- $m=12$ and $n=0$: $N=1$, with $N_0=1$ (formula above does not work)

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a very similar question in "Algebra: An Elementary Text-book for the Higher Classes of Secondary Schools and for Colleges" Vol. 2, Chap. 23, Exercise III no. 17: "In how many ways can m white and n black balls be arranged in a row so that there shall be 2r-1 contacts between white and black balls". If there is a book with solutions for this textbook I'd be helped too.

Comment: I found an answer to the first part (see below), and I am no longer interested in the second part.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to the first part of the question:

$$N_r = \binom{m}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1} +\binom{n}{r}\binom{m-1}{r-1} $$

for $r$ in the range from 1 to $\min\left(m,n\right)$.

It can be understood by considering that there are $m$ spots between the white balls that can be filled with one or more black balls. For $r$ filled spots, we get 2$r$ contacts between white and black balls. For $2r$ contacts, we can choose therefore $r$ spots out of $m$ available spots, which leads to the prefactor $\binom{m}{r}$ of the first term. This prefactor is multiplied by the number of possibilities of filling these spots. The question is in how many distinct ways can $n$ black balls be distributed over $r$ spots under the assumption that there is at least one black ball in each of the $r$ spots. In order to get $r$ groups of black balls, we use $r-1$ dividers that can be placed at $n-1$ one spots between the black balls (no periodic boundaries here), which leads to the second factor of the first term. Inverting the colors gives the second term of the sum.